# Permission denied after copying .password-store / .gnupg to a new disk

Tags: linux-mint, gnupg, password-management

I'm using pass as my password manger. Recently, I installed Mint 18.1 on a new disk, using aptik to copy `/home`, software etc. from my old Mint 17.2 installation on another disk. 
I also copied `.password-store` and `.gnupg`.

Now I can access my stored passwords, but I can't insert new files. This is the error I get when I do `pass insert -m somedir/somefile`:

```
gpg: can't create 'home/me/.password-store/somedir/somefile.gpg': Permission denied
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: Permission denied
```

Owner and group for `.password-store` and `.gnupg` is my user. Changing permissions on `.password-store` even to 777 didn't help.

```
ls -ld .gnupg/
drwx------ 3 me me 4096 May 13 19:33 .gnupg/`
ls -ld .password-store/
drwxrwxrwx 11 me me 4096 May  8 23:55 .password-store/
```

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Please post the permissions of every single path step, and also for `~/.gnupg` (`ls -ld <file/directory)>`). `chmod 777` is rarely a solution to permission issues, better try to undertand what the issue is. GnuPG sometimes even denies operation when overly broad permissions are issued!

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks, have added ls outputs above, though I'm not sure what exactly "every single path step" would include?

Comment: If any of the directories have insufficient permissions in the file's path, writing/reading the file will fail. This looks more like `somedir` does not have write permissions or similar issues.

Comment: Ah, that's it, thanks! All dirs inside .password-store belonged to root. If I remember correctly I first did pass init and then copied the contents of the old .password-store into the new one, probably using sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given GnuPG fails at creating a file in `home/me/.password-store/somedir/`:

```
gpg: can't create 'home/me/.password-store/somedir/somefile.gpg': Permission denied
```

and `.password-store` has (overly broad) permissions, it seems `somedir` does not have proper permissions set up (belongs to another user and/or misses read/write/execute permissions for your user). Verify this using `ls -ld ~/.password-store/somedir`, which should show up the folder belonging to your own user account and having read/write/execute permissions set for the user (and nobody else, since these are private files).

Following lines should fix the issue (taking ownership of the directory, which requires root privileges, and then setting read/write/execute permissions for your own user, but permissions for group and other users):

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.password-store/somedir
chmod 700 ~/.password-store/somedir
```